# How to use correctly several count(*) and select in a single table?

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a single MySQL table called `location`. My columns are:

- `idLocation`: the location id.
- `idParent`: the direct parent location id.
- `checked`: a boolean indicating if the location has been checked or not.

I'm calling level 1 location each location who has no parents / level 2 each location who has a level 1 parent / level 3 each location who has a level 2 parent.

I'm trying to find all level 1 locations and to count their undirect children (i.e. all the level 3 locations who are undirectly related) and to count how many of them have been checked.

For example, if a lvl.1 location has 4 lvl.3 children and 1 has been checked, I would like to get `1/4` as result.

I've tried several queries, but I'm a beginner and so far I've only managed to obtain the number of children of each location (including the level 2 ones, but it's not what I'm looking for).

There is a query in order to create a reproducible example:

```
CREATE TABLE location (idLocation int, idParent int, checked tinyint(1));
INSERT INTO location (idLocation, idParent, checked)
VALUES (1, null, 0), (2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 0), (4, 3, 1), (5, 3, 0), (6, 3, 0),
(7, 3, 0), (8, 3, 0), (9, null, 0), (10, 9, 0), (11, 10, 0), (12, 10, 0);
```

In this situation, we should find has a result:

- idLocation 1 with 4 level 3 childrens. 1 of them is checked.
- idLocation 9 with 2 level 3 childrens. 1 of them is checked.

Comment: Do you just have 3 levels, or there can be more?

Comment: Only 3. It's the maximum.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry, I say the same as above: please, show us some representative sample of input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do not have 'mysql' installed, but with Postgresql it could be very similar:

```
SELECT a.idparent,count(a.idparent),sum(b.checked)
FROM location AS a LEFT JOIN location AS b ON b.idparent = a.idlocal
WHERE a.idparent IS NOT NULL AND b.checked IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.idparent ;
```

`GROUP BY a.idparent`  with `count(a.idparent)` gives number of all 3rd level childern, `sum(b.checked)` gives number of checked because you defined checked as 1 and unchecked as 0, hence the sumation is enough to collect the number of checked. The `LEFT JOIN` of the table **itself** with `WHERE a.idparent IS NOT NULL` condition choose all rows where the location has any parent, and because the locations of 3rd level **do** have **no** childern, the `checked` must be `NULL`, the `b.checked IS NOT NULL` condition kicks them out.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly came to this query as an answer :

```
select idParent, count(*) as zone from location
where idParent is not null
and idParent not in (select idLocation from location where idParent is null)
and checked = 1
group by idParent;
```